# video on website with php

Tags: php, video

I'm writing a web application where users can submit pictures, videos, and descriptons of points on a Google Map. I have the application written except for the video uploading. I've read about ffmpeg to convert uploaded videos and I've also read you need a flash video player for the users to view your videos. The server-side of my site is in PHP, am I on the right track here and is there a good open source flash video player that I could use? Any general tips from those who've done something like this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the Flash video player, you could take a look at [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)

You can also take a look at these questions, which might give you some pointers :

- [How to display youtube-like video player in website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454791/how-to-display-youtube-like-video-player-in-website)
- [Making a video sharing site, need a videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146468/making-a-video-sharing-site-need-a-videoplayer)
- [PHP and FFMPEG - Performing intelligent video conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106955/php-and-ffmpeg-performing-intelligent-video-conversion)
- [Add dynamic video content (YouTube like) (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282683/add-dynamic-video-content-youtube-like-php)

Hope these help! Have fun!

Comment: From personal experience, definitely learn how to manipulate ffmpeg from the command line. Also look into forking a process off into the background, video conversion will take god awful forever and you don't want the user waiting 30 minutes with a continually loading page.